# exclude specific fields in mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

While I am trying to create a `mapper` between two `classes` in [`mapstruct`](http://mapstruct.org/),
I am getting a `warning` when I compile my code :

```
src/main/java/mapstruct/DogMapper.java:15: warning: Unmapped target property: "otherField".
    Cat convert(Dog dog);
        ^
1 warning
```

This are the two objects I am trying to map between :

**Dog**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Dog {
    private String say;
}
```

**Cat**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cat {
    private String say;
    private String otherField;
}
```

And this is my **Mapper**

```
@Mapper
public interface DogMapper {
    DogMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper( DogMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "say", target = "say")
    Cat convert(Dog dog);
}
```

I read the [`mapstruct docs`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/), and I know i can exclude this specific field in many ways :

```
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "otherField")
```

Or by this way :

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```

But my purpose in the end is to exclude the specific field called `otherField`,
from all my mappers, but not to exclude other field that I am not using.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have answered your own question, and I am not sure if I understood you correctly. You want to type `@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "otherField")` only once?

If this field is in some common base class you can use [Shared Configurations](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations). Otherwise the way you are doing with `@Mapping(ignore = true)` is the way to go.

One side note. You don't have to add `@Mapping(source = "say", target = "say")` MapStruct automatically maps properties with the same name

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar, but I have several fields I don't want to map, and I would like to avoid repeating the same `@Mapping` annotation, if possible. Basically, I'm looking for something like `@Mapping(ignore = true, target = ["id", "other", "another"])`. Is that possible nowadays?

Comment: Similar use case for me as well. It is not very clean to write 20 line to igore the unwanted filed.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might not answer the original question, but I can't answer the comment about repeating @Mapping annotation because I'm lacking reputation and I figured other people would land here looking for this.

You can totally combine annotations :

```kotlin
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "version")
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "created")
@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "updated")
fun toModel(json: JsonClass): ModelClass
```

If you have a set of fields you reuse commonly, you can also combine them by making your own annotations :

```kotlin
@Mapping(source = "version", ignore = true, target = "version")
@Mapping(source = "created", ignore = true, target = "created")
@Mapping(source = "updated", ignore = true, target = "updated")
annotation class ToModelMapping
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33140542)